# Comparing Data from Multiple Sheets Excel

Tags: excel

I have two sheets with last names and addresses in Columns A-F. I've tried using multiple formulas to compare the data, but the closest I've gotten is one row will show 'TRUE' while all other rows show '#VALUE'. Also, I've tried using different row numbers; if I use A1 to A69 it will work when comparing only Column A, but if I use A70 or greater then I get the '#VALUE'. Can anyone please help?

I've used the following, and have tried variations of them:

```
 =COUNTIF(Proper2!A:F,A8828:F8828)=6
 =COUNTIF(Proper2!A:A,A8828)=1
 =AND(EXACT(A2:A69,A16))
 =AND(Proper2!A2:A69,A16))
 =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A1:A10,1,0)),"no","yes")
```

I would like to have a column that showed either 'True/False' or 'Yes/No' for instance; Row18 A:E which matches Row3 G:K.

[image: Small Sample of the data]

Comment: *"I've tried using multiple formulas to compare the data"* Okay... but what do you want the result to be? Your question doesn't really say what you want to do, just says what you've tried but you said all of your attempts are not working. Can you show us a screenshot of your spreadsheet and some sample desired results?

Comment: *I would like to have a column that showed either 'True/False' or 'Yes/No' for instance; Row18 A:E which matches Row3 G:K.* Understood, but should this 'True' in this case appear in row 3 or row 18? In other words, is A:E the "master" to which everything is based from or is it G:K?

Comment: G:K would be the master, A:E is the data I've pulled from our database that needs to be compared to received from another origination's G:K.

Comment: For what purpose do you compare?  To find if they are identical?  To find the divergent data?  You need to be more specific.  I can compare an apple to an orange, but I need to know what I mean to delineate from the comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing I could think of is,

1) Concatenate all columns for each row and store in some column (far away say AM,AN So that it doesnt disturb). Do this for both the tables, for all rows

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2,E2)
=CONCATENATE(G2,H2,I2,J2,K2)
```

2) Now compare AM and AN using countif and if. This will tell you if there is a match or not

```
=IF(COUNTIF($AN$2:$AN$7,AM2)>0, "Match", "No Match")
```

Comment: Concat functions shouldn't have periods

Comment: It's a typo. It should be a comma

Comment: Right, I point it out so you can fix it.  People copy/paste code and may not try to troubleshoot.

Comment: Valli - I knew you meant a comma. And thanks for the help, that is working perfectly (from what I can tell) after adding it to my sheet.

Comment: @H80TW, If you think this is the answer, Can you accept this as answer?

Comment: @Valli - there you go.